# Окно с сообщением на telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Экспериментирую на питоне с библиотекой telethon. Хочу сделать такую окошку при нажатие на кнопку. Если как на скрине, то окошка появляется при нажатие на кнопу "Получить пиццу". Как мне вызвать такое окно на telethon?